# How to convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates in JS?

Tags: javascript, math, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I need to know angle of rotation in polar coordinates using X and Y from cartesian coordinates.

How to do it in JS without a lot of IF statements? I know that I can do it using [image: this system],

but I think that it will be bad for performance, because it is in animation cycle.

Comment: That will be a fair enough effort for anyone to brainstorm a solution until you have something to show like if you have kick off with something. So as a start up, just take a paper and recall everything you need and create a pseudo code/algorithm without any programming logic and then try to mold it into JS code. It could be dirty at first but improvements can be done later. If possible, you can dump the relevant section of code here to get a much better response. :)

Comment: @Rohit416 If only I could do it. I said that I know how to do it only using if constructions. I think it's obvious and I don't write here this algorithm. I ask for any other ideas how to solve this problem, maybe math library in JS or something like that.

Comment: Yes, `Math` object and its methods will definitely help. [Have you look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898720/cartesian-to-polar-coordinates) ?

Comment: @Rohit416 Thanks a lot! `atan2()` is definitely what I was looking for.

Comment: it's meaningless to optimise if statements because `atan` will be way more costly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the angle between a line and the horizontal axis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-a-line-and-the-horizontal-axis)

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: But getting all the code in all the if statements right would mean a lot more testing code to cover all the code paths. Reading it would be harder, too. A solution based on `atan2` is far easier to maintain.

Comment: @MvG as a VB.NET user, javascript _itself_ is hard enough to read and maintain :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Javascript comes with a built in function that does what is represented in the image: `Math.atan2()`

`Math.atan2()` takes `y, x` as arguments and returns the angle in radians.

For example:

```
x = 3
y = 4    
Math.atan2(y, x) //Notice that y is first!

//returns 0.92729521... radians, which is 53.1301... degrees
```

I wrote this function to convert from Cartesian Coordinates to Polar Coordinates, returning the distance and the angle (in radians):

```
function cartesian2Polar(x, y){
    distance = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    radians = Math.atan2(y,x) //This takes y first
    polarCoor = { distance:distance, radians:radians }
    return polarCoor
}
```

You can use it like this to get the angle in radians:

```
cartesian2Polar(5,5).radians
```

Lastly, if you need degrees, you can convert radians to degrees like this

```
degrees = radians * (180/Math.PI)
```

Comment: Here is my 1 line version of the same function:
const c2p = pt => [Math.sqrt(pt[0] ** 2 + pt[1] ** 2), Math.atan2(pt[1], pt[0])];
However, it also takes the argument as an array [x,y] and returns the array [distance,radian].
Conversely, here is also my 1 line function for polar to cartesian:
const p2c = pt => [pt[0] * Math.cos(pt[1]), pt[0] * Math.sin(pt[1])];

Comment: the hypotenuse function `hypot(x, y)` can be used instead of `sqrt(x*x+y*y)`