# Breaking a rectangle into four triangles

Tags: java, joystick

I am trying to use a joystick for controlling something, but the only way I can control it is by having a direction to a corner instead of a side. For example, I would read up when the joystick points to the top left corner. I do that with an if x is greater than 500 (the midpoint) and if the y is greater than 500. Is there a way to make it read when it goes to a side instead of a corner?

```
if(analogRead(0) < 500 && analogRead(1) < 500){
    y--;
  } else if (analogRead(0) > 500 && analogRead(1) < 500){
    x++;
  } else if (analogRead(0) < 500 && analogRead(1) > 500){
    x--;
  } else if(analogRead(0)>500 && analogRead(1)>500){
    y++; 
  }
```

I also do know that this is very badly written code, but this code is only for trying to read from a side rather than a corner.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your X and Y values into an angle and distance from the center, then compare against the angle.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043899/3429323) you can do the conversion:

```
const radianAngle = Math.atan2(y,x);
```

Then compare it agains the four quadrants:

```
0 <= angle < Pi/2 (quadrant A)
Pi/2 <= angle < Pi (quadrant B)
Pi <= angle < 3Pi/2 (Quadrant C)
3Pi/2 <= angle <= 2Pi (Quadrant D)
```

Than take a decision acording to each quadrant you are.

**Edit:** The original question doesn't say what language is used, so by the syntax I guesses (erroneously) that it was Javascript, but it's Java.

For Java the logic is the same, it also provides the atan2 function.

The implementation will be like:

```
double x = analogRead(0);
double y = analogRead(1);

double angle = Math.atan2(x, y);
int quadrant = (int) Math.max(1, Math.ceil(2 * angle / Math.PI));
```

The `quadrant` variable will be a quadrant from 1 to 4, you can use it value to take a decision.

Comment: Can you show me how that would work in java?

Comment: The logic is the same, java also have the atan2 math function.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-math-atan2-java/amp/

Comment: I've edited the answer with a valid java code to get the quadrant.

Comment: Thank you, does this break it into the 4 standard quadrants or into 4 triangles?

Comment: It only takes account of the angle of the joystick from the center (the angle that x and y makes from 0,0), not the force (the size of x and y)