# Geometry help: Plotting along a path between 2 points in a circle JS

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, geometry, 2d

I'm trying to plot a *specified number of steps* between 2 points on a polar circle graph. The angle (radius) is represented by HUE, from 0 to 360. The theta is represented by CHROMA (strength).

I specify how many steps I want and blend these 2 independent values, but the result is not what I expect, the points go around the circle, where-as I want it to go across (see screenshot).

I'm not very strong in geometry, any help would be much appreciated!

[SEE THIS EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY6kT.jpg)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Colour Chart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartContainer1"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>

        const pigments = [{
            key: "A",
            name: "Red",
            hue: 18,
            chroma: 14,
        },
        {
            key: "B",
            name: "Blue",
            hue: 279,
            chroma: 10,
        }
        ];

        function getNumberBlend(min, max, totalSteps) {
            let steps = new Array(totalSteps);
            let distance = max - min;
            for (i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
                steps[i] = min + distance * (i / (totalSteps - 1));
            }
            return steps;
        }


        // Define properties
        let radiusData = new Array();
        let thetaData = new Array();
        let textData = new Array();
        let totalSteps = 15;

        // Plot blends from each pigment to the next
        let chromaBlend = getNumberBlend(pigments[0]["chroma"], pigments[1]["chroma"], totalSteps);
        let hueBlend = getNumberBlend(pigments[0]["hue"], pigments[1]["hue"], totalSteps);

        for (let i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
            radiusData.push(chromaBlend[i]);
            thetaData.push(hueBlend[i]);      
            textData.push("");
        }

        let plotlyData = [
            {
                type: "scatterpolar",
                mode: "markers+text",
                r: radiusData,
                theta: thetaData,
                text: textData,                
                marker: {                    
                    color: "#000000"                    
                },
                subplot: "polar"
            }
        ]

        let plotlyLayout = {            
            polar: {                
                radialaxis: {
                    range: [0, 18],
                    tickfont: {
                        size: 8
                    },
                    color: "rgb(0,153,204)",
                },
                angularaxis: {
                    rotation: 108, // Start with 5R at North
                    direction: "clockwise",
                }
            }
        }


        Plotly.newPlot("chartContainer1", plotlyData, plotlyLayout)

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to blend between the different values, but I can't seem to figure out the way to correctly do this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You want points along a straight line between your two points, but you are using a polar co-ordinate system ( angle and radius ).  IOt is a difficult task, UNLESS you convert to use cartesian co-ordinates ( x and y ).

So I would sugest:

- Write code to convert between polar and cartesian co-ords.
- Convert your two points to cartesian
- Calculate the formula ( y = mx + c ) of the line between points
- Calculate the points along the line.
- Convert points back to polar co-ords.

Comment: I've followed your direction, and updated my code below. It still doesn't work right, are you able to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, getNumberBlend is saying "add some to the angle, add some to the radius," so the output makes sense. Since the points you want are on a line, it's complicated because lines are harder in polar coordinates. I think something like this will work though:

The easiest way would be if you could possibly write the entire graph in cartesian coordinates. Then you could use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175896/finding-a-point-along-a-line-a-certain-distance-away-from-another-point) method. Look at the first answer.

If you can't do the entire program in cartesian, then you could convert your two points into cartesian, use the method above to generate the points needed, then convert those to polar coordinates and plot.

[Converting to cartesian in JS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-convert-polar-co-ordinates-to-equivalent-cartesian-co-ordinates/) (Scroll down, JS near bottom)

[Converting to polar in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219051/how-to-convert-cartesian-coordinates-to-polar-coordinates-in-js)

The issue with attempting to find a point at a distance along a line in polar format is that you'll notice, radius does not change uniformly in increments. It starts at 8, gets smaller, then increases again to 14. In cartesian coordinates, x and y uniformly increase or decrease along a line.

Also, I tried converting your points to cartesian and plotting a line. It turns out similar to your desired line but not the same... I haven't messed much with JS before, but it looks like you told the plot to go clockwise about the axis. Normally, degrees and radians are measured counter-clockwise from the x-axis, so saying clockwise might have it go the wrong way and end up in the wrong quadrant.

Comment: I've followed your direction, and updated my code below. It still doesn't work right, are you able to have a look? @mixed.success

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the output it's giving now? Just from looking at the code, I can see you forgot to do the middle step - actually calculating your new points on the line.  x and y need to be scaled based on the distance you want, not have the distance added right to them. For example, if your line happened to be vertical, you definitely don't want anything being added to x. That's why you need to use the math from the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've tried implementing your comments and added a function that first converts my polar points to cartesian. After that, it creates the number blends for the cartesian numbers. Finally, it converts the new cartesian points into polar, which are used on the Plotly chart.

It seems logical to me, but theres something wrong that I can't seem to figure out. I've added debugging to try and figure out where it is. But I'm stumped.

```js
        const pigments = [{
            key: "A",
            name: "Red",
            hue: 18,
            chroma: 14,
        },
        {
            key: "B",
            name: "Blue",
            hue: 279,
            chroma: 10,
        }
        ];


        // CODE FROM: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-convert-polar-co-ordinates-to-equivalent-cartesian-co-ordinates/ 
        // Function to convert degree to radian
        function ConvertDegToRad(degree) {
            let pi = 3.14159;
            return (degree * (pi / 180.0));
        }

        // Function to convert polar coordinate to cartesian
        function ConvertToCartesian(polar) {
            // Convert degrees to radian            
            polar.radians = ConvertDegToRad(polar.radians);

            // Applying the formula:
            // x = rcos(theta), y = rsin(theta)
            let cartesian = { "x": polar.radians * Math.cos(polar.distance), "y": polar.radians * Math.sin(polar.distance) };

            // Print cartesian coordinates
            return cartesian;
        }

        // CODE FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219051/how-to-convert-cartesian-coordinates-to-polar-coordinates-in-js
        // Function to convert cartesian to polar coordinate
        function ConvertRadToDeg(radians) {
            let degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
            return degrees;
        }

        function ConvertToPolar(x, y) {
            console.log("x: " + x + ", Y:" + y);
            let radians = Math.atan2(y, x); //This takes y first
            let distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            let polarCoor = { "radians": radians, "distance": distance };
            //console.log("radians: " + polarCoor.radians + " distance: " + polarCoor.distance);
            return polarCoor;
        }

        // Function to create specified incremement of numbers 
        // between (and including) start and end
        function getNumberBlend(min, max, totalSteps) {
            let steps = new Array(totalSteps);
            let distance = max - min;
            for (i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {
                steps[i] = min + distance * (i / (totalSteps - 1));
            }
            return steps;
        }

        // Define properties
        let xData = new Array();
        let yData = new Array();
        let radiansData = new Array();
        let distanceData = new Array();
        let textData = new Array();
        const totalSteps = 15;
        const distanceMax = 18;


        // Set Polar Coords (radian,distance)
        let polarStart = {
            "radians": pigments[0]["hue"],
            "distance": pigments[0]["chroma"]
        };
        let polarEnd = {
            "radians": pigments[1]["hue"],
            "distance": pigments[1]["chroma"]
        };
        console.log("Polar start: " + polarStart.radians + "," + polarStart.distance + "\nend: " + polarEnd.radians + "," + polarEnd.distance);

        // Convert Polar to Cartesian (x,y)
        let cartesianStart = ConvertToCartesian({ "radians": polarStart.radians, "distance": polarStart.distance });
        let cartesianEnd = ConvertToCartesian({ "radians": polarEnd.radians, "distance": polarEnd.distance });
        console.log("Cartesian start: " + cartesianStart.x + "," + cartesianStart.y + ",\nend: " + cartesianEnd.x + "," + cartesianEnd.y);

        // Create number blend between start-end X
        let xBlend = getNumberBlend(cartesianStart.x, cartesianEnd.x, totalSteps);
        console.log("Blend X: " + xBlend);

        // Create number blend between start-end Y
        let yBlend = getNumberBlend(cartesianStart.y, cartesianEnd.y, totalSteps);        
        console.log("Blend Y: " + yBlend);


        // Convert X/Y Pairs back to Polar
        for (let i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++) {

            // Convert X/Y to Polar
            let polar = ConvertToPolar(xBlend[i], yBlend[i]);
            
            // Convert Radians to Degrees
            polar.radians = ConvertRadToDeg(polar.radians);

            polar.distance = polar.distance * distanceMax;

            // Round numbers
            polar.radians = polar.radians.toFixed(2);
            polar.distance = polar.distance.toFixed(2);

            // Push to chart data
            radiansData.push(polar.radians);
            distanceData.push(polar.distance);
            textData.push("");

            //console.log("Final polar radians: " + polar[0] + ", distance: " + polar[1]);
        }

        console.log("radiansData: " + radiansData.length + "\n" + radiansData + "\n\ndistanceData: " + distanceData.length + "\n" + distanceData + "\n\ntextData: " + textData.length + "\n" + textData);


        let plotlyData = [
            {
                type: "scatterpolar",
                mode: "markers+text",
                r: radiansData,
                theta: distanceData,
                text: textData,
                marker: {
                    color: "#000000"
                },
                subplot: "polar"
            }
        ]

        let plotlyLayout = {
            polar: {
                radialaxis: {
                    range: [0, 18],
                    tickfont: {
                        size: 8
                    },
                    color: "rgb(0,153,204)",
                },
                angularaxis: {
                    rotation: 108, // Start with 5R at North
                    direction: "clockwise",
                }
            }
        }


        Plotly.newPlot("chartContainer1", plotlyData, plotlyLayout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Colour Chart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartContainer1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```